# Django Allowed_Hosts Error.

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a django server with  ./manage.py runserver

But appears this error:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Do not put your question in the title.

Comment: @Octo: The stack overflow guidelines specifically recommends that the title _should_ be in the form of a question. See the first section of this guide: [ask]. That said, it's also good to keep the title as short as possible.

Comment: @HåkenLid OK, I knew there was something wrong with the titel, just didnt know what.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? I ran into the same issue and this post helped.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just do this

```
myapp
|______myapp
           |______settings.py
```

Inside that there should be a line:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Make it instead

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
```

Comment: You can also use "*" to accept any host. And when DEBUG is True, django will not check the host at all. This feature is a protection against certain kinds of cross site requests, so it's only needed in production, and you can safely turn it off when you are doing development on localhost. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: @HåkenLid - "In older versions, ALLOWED_HOSTS wasn’t checked if DEBUG=True. This was also changed in Django 1.9.11 and 1.8.16 to prevent a DNS rebinding attack." - From the docs link in your comment

Comment: That specific security measure seems quite paranoid to me. How common are these kinds of attacks? But I guess it's good that django has strict security defaults.

Comment: in my case, I had to change that configuration in the `local_settings.py` to work. I changed that in the file `settings.py` and didn't work for me, any guesses? @Octo